# Separating a continuous string Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have been playing around with this code that I'm trying to get to read the string of text without spaces. The code needs to separate the string by identifying the all capital letters using regular expressions. However I can’t seem to get it to display the capital letters.

```
import re
mystring = 'ThisIsStringWithoutSpacesWordsTextManDogCow!'
wordList = re.sub("[^\^a-z]"," ",mystring)
print (wordList)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
re.sub("([A-Z])"," \\1",mystring).split()
```

This prepends a space in front of every capital letter and splits on these spaces.

Output:

```
['This',
 'Is',
 'String',
 'Without',
 'Spaces',
 'Words',
 'Text',
 'Man',
 'Dog',
 'Cow!']
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `sub`, you could use `re.findall` to find all the words (beginning with an uppercase letter followed by zero or more non-uppercase characters) and then join them back together:

```
>>> ' '.join(re.findall(r'[A-Z][^A-Z]*', mystring))
'This Is String Without Spaces Words Text Man Dog Cow!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>>> re.split('([A-Z][a-z]*)', mystring)
['', 'This', '', 'Is', '', 'String', '', 'Without', '', 'Spaces', '', 'Words', '', 'Text', '', 'Man', '', 'Dog', '', 'Cow', '!']
```

This gives you word per word output. Even the `!` is separated out.
If you dont want the extra `''`, then you can remove it by `filter(lambda x: x != '', a)` if `a` is the output of above command

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x != '', a)
['This', 'Is', 'String', 'Without', 'Spaces', 'Words', 'Text', 'Man', 'Dog', 'Cow', '!']
```

Comment: filter(None, a) will be better :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not a regular expression solution, but you can do it in normal code as well :-)

```
mystring = 'ThisIsStringWithoutSpacesWordsTextManDogCow!'
output_list = []
for i, letter in enumerate(mystring):
    if i!=index and letter.isupper():
            output_list.append(mystring[index:i])
            index = i
else:
    output_list.append(mystring[index:i])
```

Now on topic, this could be something what you are looking for?

```
mystring = re.sub(r"([a-z\d])([A-Z])", r'\1 \2', mystring)
# Makes the string space separated. You can use split to convert it to list
mystring = mystring.split()
```